# Input string was not in a correct format with SUM

Tags: string, sum, double, cultureinfo

I have a problem calculating from double to string when I have a sum of a list.
When the language setting is changed, I've tried using InvariantCulture but I've not managed to get it to work. Does anyone have any tips on how to process this?

Code looks like:

```
List<string> Moms_F = new List<string>();
double tot_Moms_F = Moms_F.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x));
AssignControls(GetControls(wordDoc, "tot_Moms_F"), tot_Moms_F.ToString());
```

What I tried to to was

```
            CultureInfo ci;

            ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

and then adding

```
double tot_Moms_F = Moms_F.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(ci));
```

but I then get the error :
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this if anyone stumbles accross this issue and has the same problem:

```
CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
                ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
float tot_Moms_F = Moms_F.Sum(x => float.Parse(x,NumberStyles.Any, ci));
```

One thing to note tough is that the printed value is , instead of . something too lokinto